# Finding all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, free-product

Consider the group that is the free product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, that is $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2=\left\langle  a,b\;\vert \;a^2=b^2=e \right\rangle$. I'm trying to find all of its proper and non trivial subgroups. I can find at least one subgroup, ie I think that there is a subgroup of $G$ generated by $ab$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. But that's about all the obvious one I can see straight away and I'm not sure how to go about finding the rest.

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm trying to find the all of the connected covering spaces of $\mathbb{R}P^2\vee\mathbb{R}P^2$. If I'm not mistaken, this space has $G$ as its fundamental group, hence identifying subgroups of $\pi_1(G)$ would allow me to classify the covering spaces (right?).

If anyone can provide some insight I'd appreciate that, thank you!

EDIT: I forgot to write it down but of course by definition $H*H'$ contains both $H$ and $H'$ as subgroups so here we also have $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a subgroup. $G$ even has two such subgroups, the one generated by $a$ and the one generated by $b$ (right?).

Comment: It might help you to know that this is just the infinite dihedral group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Not particularly as I don't know much about it, but I'll see what I can find online thank you.

Comment: Can you see what form all the elements look like? They have a particular nice form.

Comment: Do you mean $a^2=b^2=e$? Or equivalently $a^2, b^2$?

Comment: @user1729 I didnt see it, but I think I remember reading something like $(ab)^n$ or $(ab)^na$ or $(ba)^nb$. I will try to figure it out in a bit, thanks

Comment: @Arthur I meant $a^2=b^2=e$

Comment: @notananalyst Yes, that form. The point is that there are no $a^2$ or $b^2$ terms. The next thing to realise is to notice, via this form, the importance of the subgroup generated by $ab$.

Comment: @user1729 oh ok, yeah, I think I see what you mean, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t = ab$. Then $G = \langle a,t \mid a^2=1, a^{-1}ta=t^{-1} \rangle$ is the infinite dihedral group.

The subgroups are as follows (apologies in advance for any mistakes).

$\mathbf{Type\ 1.}$ The trivial subgroup.

$\mathbf{Type\ 2.}$ Infinite cyclic subgroups $C_k = \langle t^k \rangle$, one for each integer $k>0$. Note that $C_k$ has index $k$ in $\langle t \rangle$.

$\mathbf{Type\ 3.}$ Reflection subgroups $R_k= \langle t^ka \rangle$, one for each $k \in {\mathbb Z}$. They have order $2$.

$\mathbf{Type\ 4.}$ Infinite dihedral subgroups $D_{ki} = \langle t^k,t^ia \rangle$, one for each $k>0$ and $0\le i < k$. These have finite index $k$ in $G$.

Comment: @user1729 Isn't $bt^k = t^{-k-1}a$ (or something similar)?

Comment: Yes, it is! (e.g. $bab=(ab)^{-2}a$.) Although writing these as conjugates would maybe help others not to make this mistake?

Comment: @DerekHolt I think you are correct, the subgroups of the form $\langle bt^k \rangle$ are included in those of the form $\langle t^k a\rangle$ since you took $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think the way I have presented it is more illuminating if you are thinking of the groups as the infinite dihedral group with generators $a$ and $t$ rather than $a$ and $b$. But it might have been helpful to mention that the reflection groups split into two conjugacy classes, according to the parity of $k$.